# Get iterator or reference of object just inserted to container

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers

When I `insert()` an object into container such [std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/), how can I get reference/iterator/pointer to its location without searching for it ( e.g. `find()`; that would mean unnecessary overhead ).

I mean, the container datastructure should know where it just stored my object, without searching.

consider this code:

```
class Node{
    public:
    int    id;
    double mass;
};

std::unordered_map<uint32_t,Node> nodes;
﻿
Node& tryInsertNode( uint32_t key, const Node& node ){
    auto nod_it = nodes.find( key );
    if ( nod_it == nodes.end() ){
        nodes.insert( {key, node} );
        nod_it = nodes.find( key ); // this is silly, I don't want to do this !!!
        // nod_it = ???             // JUST GIVE ME MY POINTER !!!
    }else{
        nod_it->second = node;
    };
    return nod_it->second;
}
```

I need to return reference / pointer / iterator to the instance of `class Node` which is allocated inside `std::unordered_map<uint32_t,Node> nodes;` so that I can modify the contend of this node later, without paying cost of `find()`

Sure, I would not have this problem when I use pointers i.e. :
`std::unordered_map<uint32_t,Node*> nodes;`

But I think that in my particular case would be `std::unordered_map<uint32_t,Node>` preferable for performance reasons (i.e. less jumping in memory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) returns an iterator* to the newly-inserted element.

So you already have it. It's just that, in your code at the moment, you're throwing it away.

---

* Well, or a pair that wraps it. It depends on which `insert` you call. In your case:

```
nod_it = nodes.insert( {key, node} ).first;
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I did not read reference of `std::unordered_map::insert()` carefully, and I expected that insert should return pointer/reference/iterator to `Node`, not `Pair<Iterator<Pair<key,Node>>,bool>` ... so I was confused by error message.